# how to create a subway map visualisation of my data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization

Found the nice figure below in a paper (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25626705). It visualises the workflows of different laboratories and illustrates nicely where they diverge. Could see this being useful for many other datasets.

Is there a tool that facilitates creation of these kinds of maps from a set of data (i.e. avoids me to have to draw this in a drawing app from scratch)?

Can I do something like this in ggplot2?

[image: subway map]

Comment: Do you have some example data? I think something similar might be possible in ggplot2, but will require some fiddling.

Comment: Here's a pretty neat tool: http://memoryunderground.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is my suggestion for a bus-stop map (at the end there is the plot as an attachment):

```
library(ggplot2)

# DF
datos <- data.frame(origen=c(rep("Ruta 126", 7), rep("Ruta 131", 6), rep("Ruta 132", 6)), 
                destino=c("San José", "Jericó", "Guadarrama", "San Juan Norte", "San Juan Sur", "Río Conejo", "Loma Larga",
                          "Cartago", "Copalchí", "El Alumbre", "San Juan Norte", "San Juan Sur", "Loma Larga",
                          "San Juan Norte", "Calle Valverde", "Calle Abarca", "San Juan Sur", "Río Conejo", "Loma Larga"),
                subsidio=c("","-345","-135","-400","-325","-155","400", "", "230", "255", "515", "530", "2150", rep("",6)))

# Levels to factor
datos$destino <- factor(datos$destino, levels = c("San José", "Cartago","Jericó", "Copalchí", "Guadarrama", "El Alumbre", "San Juan Norte",  "Calle Valverde", "Calle Abarca", "San Juan Sur", "Río Conejo", "Loma Larga"))
datos$origen <- factor(datos$origen, levels = c("Ruta 126", "Ruta 132", "Ruta 131"))

# Groups for geom_text
etiqueta1 <- c("San José", "Cartago","Jericó", "Copalchí", "Guadarrama", "El Alumbre", "Calle Valverde", "Calle Abarca", "Río Conejo")
etiqueta2 <- c("San Juan Norte", "San Juan Sur", "Loma Larga")

# group for geom_label
text1 <- c("-345","-135","-400","-325","-155","400")
text2 <- c("230", "255", "515", "530", "2150")

# Plot
ggplot(datos, aes(destino, origen, group=origen)) +
  geom_line(size=10, aes(color=origen)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=7, xend=7, y= 1, yend=3), size=1, color="grey20", linetype=3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=10, xend=10, y= 1, yend=3), size=1, color="grey20", linetype=3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=12, xend=12, y= 1, yend=3), size=1, color="grey20", linetype=3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=11, xend=11, y= 1, yend=2), size=1, color="grey20", linetype=3) +
  geom_point(size=6) +
  scale_color_manual("", values = c("steelblue3", "tomato2", "forestgreen")) +
  geom_text(data= subset(datos, destino %in% etiqueta1), aes(label=destino), nudge_y = .25, size=3, angle=45, fontface="bold") +
  geom_text(data= subset(datos, destino %in% etiqueta2 & origen== "Ruta 126"), aes(label=destino), nudge_y = -.2, size=4, fontface="bold") +
  geom_label(data= subset(datos, subsidio %in% text1 & origen== "Ruta 126"), aes(label=subsidio), nudge_y = -.5, size=4, fontface="bold") +
  geom_label(data= subset(datos, subsidio %in% text2 & origen== "Ruta 131"), aes(label=subsidio), nudge_y = .52, size=4, fontface="bold") +
  labs(x="", y="") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow=3, reverse = T)) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(3,.5,3,.5), "cm"))
```

[bus-stop map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkeZ8.jpg)