# Subway map using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a subway map or something similar to this picture using my Flow Cytometry Data in ggplot2:

[image: FlowCytometrySubwayMap]

I can provide reproducible data of full paths where nods are clearly seen:

```
fullPopulationPaths = 
 c("root",                                                                                                                            
   "/Single Cells",                                                                                                                   
   "/Single Cells/Live",                                                                                                              
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45 int CD123+",                                                                                              
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45 int CD123+/CD45 int CD123+ DR-CD38+ Basophils",                                                           
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45+",                                                                                                        
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45+/Lymphocytes",                                                                                            
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45+/Lymphocytes/CD3+ TCR+",                                                                                  
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45+/Lymphocytes/CD3+ TCR+/CCR7+TCRgd+",                                                                      
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45+/Lymphocytes/CD3+ TCR+/CCR7-",                                                                            
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45+/Lymphocytes/CD3+ TCR+/CCR7-CD45RA++TCRgd+",                                                              
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45+/Lymphocytes/CD3+ TCR-",                                                                                  
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45+/Lymphocytes/CD3+ TCR-/CD3+ CD56-" ,                                                                      
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45+/Lymphocytes/CD3+ TCR-/CD3+ CD56-/CD4+",                                                                  
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45+/Lymphocytes/CD3+ TCR-/CD3+ CD56-/CD4+/CD4+CD45RA++CCR7+"   ,                                             
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45+/Lymphocytes/CD3+ TCR-/CD3+ CD56-/CD4+/CD4+CD45RA++CCR7+/naive CD4+" ,                                    
   "/Single Cells/Live/CD45+/Lymphocytes/CD3+ TCR-/CD3+ CD56-/CD4+/CD4+CD45RA-CCR7+")
```

I tried to use the code from the answer of this post [how to create a subway map visualisation of my data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113267/how-to-create-a-subway-map-visualisation-of-my-data) but it did not work for my data.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably convert the data into an igraph and plot using ggraph. The most difficult part is positioning the labels:

```r
library(igraph)
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(fullPopulationPaths, "/")[-(1:2)], 
        function(x) {
        x <- x[nzchar(x)]
        x[length(x) + c(-1, 0)]
        })) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  graph_from_data_frame() |>
  as_tbl_graph() |>
  ggraph() +
  geom_edge_diagonal(aes(colour = factor(from)), width = 2) +
  geom_node_point(size = 5) +
  geom_node_point(size = 2, colour = "white") +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), 
                 nudge_y = c(0.3, -0.5, 0, 0, -0.5, -0.3, 0, 0, 0,
                             -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0, 0, -0.5, -0.5),
                 nudge_x = c(0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 
                             0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0)/10,
                 hjust = c(0.5, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5,
                           0.5, 0, 1, 0.8, 0.5),
                 fontface = "italic") +
  scale_edge_color_discrete(guide = "none") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This gets me closer to what I want! However, I want to have more easy-to-use piece of code, so when I have either 10 or 200 nodes, it will place the names on them automatically.... but igraph is a good option I believe